# Mean Square Error (MSE) Root Mean Square Error (RMSE)

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm on a project for the study that I used the `mean_square_error` from `skelarn` to get my MSE and RMSE.

I can´t understand what the information means.

I'm using a dataset about House Sales and I want to predict the price of the house using Linear Regression. When I put my predict price and real price, I got the results:

> MSE: 1114197668.6920328 RMSE: 33379.59958855158

What this information really means actually? That my predict will have a mean difference in price about `33379.60`?

```
            MSE = mean_squared_error(predict,testSalePrice)
            RMSE = np.sqrt(MSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mean Squared Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error):

> In statistics, the mean squared error (MSE) or mean squared deviation
>   (MSD) of an estimator (of a procedure for estimating an unobserved
>   quantity) measures the average of the squares of the errors.

So for example let's assume you have three datapoints:

```
Price Predicted
1900  2000
2000  2000
2100  2000
```

Then the MSE is: `1/3 * ((-100)*(-100)+ (0)*(0) + (100)*(100)) = 1/3 * (20000) = 6000`

The perfect one would be 0, but this you will probably not reach. You have to interpret it in comparison with your actual value range.

The RMSE in this case would be: `SQRT(6000) = 77,..`

This is more intepretable, that means on average you are 77 away from your prediction, which makes sense if you see the three results

Comment: Thanks a lot! Simple and understandable explanation!

Comment: "hat means on average you are 77 away from your prediction, which makes sense" I belive this is interpretatoin of MAE nor RMSE